# Error sharing semaphore id

Tags: c, multithreading, process, shared-memory, semaphore

I am writing a multiprocess program in which one master program executes other ones. They share a memory area and their accesses are controlled by a semaphore.

In the master program I wrote:

```
#define shared_memory_path "."
#define semaphore_path "."
#define shared_memory_char 'a'
#define semaphore_char 'b'
shm_key = ftok(shared_memory_path,shared_memory_char);
sem_key = ftok(semaphore_path,semaphore_char);
semid = semget(sem_key,3,IPC_CREAT|0664);
shmid = shmget(shm_key,sizeof(myDataStructure),IPC_CREAT|0664);
//initialization of the semaphores
```

Then in the two slave programs i wrote:

```
shm_key = ftok(shared_memory_path,shared_memory_char);
sem_key = ftok(semaphore_path,semaphore_char);
/*so i will have the same keys of the master program (the printf() function
print exactly the same keys  */
shm_id = shmget(shm_key,0,IPC_CREAT|0664);
sem_id = semget(sem_key,0,IPC_CREAT|0664); 
//I verified that the shm_id is recognized by master and slaves (with a printf())
```

The problem is that the sem_id returns a -1 value in the slaves (in the master it is a correct value). I used similar instructions for both shared memory and semaphores, but the shared memory is correctly recognized, the sempahore is not.

I found other code that applies the same solution but that code is working.

Comment: Have you checked the `errno` value that `semget()` is leaving behind?

Comment: No, i didn't check the errno

Comment: You should probably do that to see what error you're getting.

Comment: It was : invalid argument

Comment: Reading from the man page, the error is probably that you're passing a 0 as the amount of semaphores in the set, but the set doesn't exist yet and it is trying to create it; therefore it fails since it cannot create a set with no semaphores.

Comment: The set already exists and is created by the master program. The slave program has the same key and should not create a new semaphore.

Comment: Are you sure the master program is running _before_ the slaves, then? This looks like a typical race condition issue.

Comment: Yes because the fork() is before the exec(). Moreover, the instruction for shared memory and semaphore are very similar and they are written in almost the same order in all the .c files, but the shared memory is successfully used and the semaphore not.

Comment: @EagleOne *Yes because the fork() is before the exec().*  That actually means "No".  If you don't explicitly synchronize actions, you can not be sure one happens before the other, even if it "works".  Assuming you're runnong on Linux, what's the output from `ipcs -s`?

Comment: @Andrew Henle When the fork is called, the semid and semid parameters all surely already set by the master process, because it is the only process active. After setting semid and semid, the master program uses the fork() and then the exec(). So the actions have a precise order of execution